# What is Copy Local if the <Private> element is ommitted from .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

According to the Microsoft documentation the `<Private>` child element of a `<Reference>` element in a .csproj file is defined thus:

```
Private     Optional boolean. Specifies whether the reference should be copied to the output folder. This attribute matches the Copy Local property of the reference that's in the Visual Studio IDE.
```

However I have several projects with `<Reference>` elements that do not contain a `<Private>` child element, and if I look at the project references in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer window, sometimes the Copy Local for these references shows a True and sometimes as False. I am writing a utility that reads a .csproj file and I need to be able to ascertain whether a reference is Copy Local or not. Obviously the documentation is not telling the full story. Does anyone know how Copy Local is determined if the `<Private>` element is absent?

Comment: There seems to be [an awful lot of logic involved](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/AssemblyDependency/Reference.cs#L949).

Comment: Wow! I see what you mean. I guess that's answered the question though, thanks for that. You should post that as an answer I think.

Comment: (off topic) Can you share your tool? Hope it is an open source

Comment: :-). Don't you want to know what it does first?